# Is there an equivalent to an "On Record Changed" event for Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to set permissions for my form fields (continuous form) and permissions need to be re-evaluated every time a different record gains focus/selection. Right now the only way I've found is to have an OnFocus event for each editable control, but there's gotta be a better way...

I've already tried MouseMove, OnClick, etc. but they don't seem to work when clicking/moving from a control in one record to the next without clicking over empty space first. Also MouseMove seems to have a limit to how frequently it responds.

I would also appreciate something equivalent to an "On Focus Changed" event, if "On Record Changed" is not possible.

Comment: have you tried OnCurrent?  Or maybe OnDirty?  You can also try OnAfterUpdate.

Comment: Oh, I haven't tried OnCurrent. Didn't catch my attention when I was going through the list. If you create an answer, I'll set it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try OnCurrent, or maybe OnDirty, and can also try OnAfterUpdate.
I usually put stops in all of the candidate events when I'm not sure which one to use.  There are differences, but running your application and seeing when the events fire can help you decide which one to use.

Answer (score 2):

The event you are looking for is : Form_Current

Comment: Comparing this to the other answer your proposal seems oddly off the apparent naming pattern.